# Uppercase na primeira letra de todas as palavras de uma coluna no MySQL

Tags: mysql

Como eu faço para que a **primeira letra** de todas as palavras em uma coluna especifica seja convertida para **maiúscula** utilizando **MySQL** puro?

Exemplo:

```
gustavo silva
Guilherme souza
joão Silva
maria souza
```

Para:

```
Gustavo Silva
Guilherme Souza
João Silva
Maria Souza
```

Comment: https://www.google.co.jp/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ucfirst%20mysql

Answer (score 10):

Esta funcionalidade não existe no MySQL, mas podes definir a seguinte função para obter o resultado que desejas. Considero que isto seja MySQL puro, por isso, para quê reinventar a roda, não?

```
CREATE FUNCTION CAP_FIRST (input VARCHAR(255))

RETURNS VARCHAR(255)

DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN
    DECLARE len INT;
    DECLARE i INT;

    SET len   = CHAR_LENGTH(input);
    SET input = LOWER(input); -- Opcional mas pode ser util quando queres formatar nomes
    SET i = 0;

    WHILE (i < len) DO
        IF (MID(input,i,1) = ' ' OR i = 0) THEN
            IF (i < len) THEN
                SET input = CONCAT(
                    LEFT(input,i),
                    UPPER(MID(input,i + 1,1)),
                    RIGHT(input,len - i - 1)
                );
            END IF;
        END IF;
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN input;
END;
```

Para usar basta:

```
SELECT CAP_FIRST('gustavo silva')
```

Irá devolver

```
Gustavo Silva
```

Os créditos não são meus, apenas me deparei com o mesmo problema recentemente e foi esta a solução que usei.

http://joezack.com/2008/10/20/mysql-capitalize-function/

Edit: 
Deixo apenas um comentário final. Esta funcionalidade deveria ser implementada no frontend, sempre que possível. Manipulação de strings e loops são normalmente bastante problemáticos para os SGBDs e devem ser evitados sempre que possível. Principalmente se é uma query que vai ser executada muitas vezes.

Answer (score 2):

Este código abaixo irá resolver o seu problema:

```
UPDATE tabela SET coluna =
SELECT CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(coluna FROM 1 FOR 1)), 
SUBSTRING( coluna FROM 2 FOR LENGTH(coluna))) FROM tabela
```

Comment: @Gustavo Piucco, desse jeito é mais simples, você pode criar uma rotina passando a cláusula "where", na reposta anterior será mais lento para executar

Answer (score -1):

A solução é ótima, mas, encontra um problema em português onde usamos o "da", o "de", o "do" e o "e", por exemplo "JOSE DA SILVA", usando a função retornaria "Jose Da Silva", em vez de "Jose da Silva". Prar corrigir isso basta usar o REPLACE antes do RETURN final:
....

```
SET input=REPLACE(input,' Da ',' da ');
SET input=REPLACE(input,' De ',' de ');
SET input=REPLACE(input,' Do ',' do ');
SET input=REPLACE(input,' E ',' e ');
RETURN input;
```